# how I can update my entity in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

In my wcf service I have method as Operation Contract like following :

```
public void Update(long id, string docNo, Nullable<int> item, string regNo, string payCode, string fixVar,
        string effectiveDate, string calcBase, Nullable<decimal> value, string costCenter, string subAcc,
        string docReference, string comment)
    {
        using (WFS006Entities dbu = new WFS006Entities())
        {
            NIOCPay_PayDetail doc = dbu.NIOCPay_PayDetail.Where(it => it.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.DocNo = docNo;
                doc.Item = item.HasValue ? item.Value : 0;
                doc.RegNo = regNo;
                doc.PayCode = payCode;
                doc.FixVar = fixVar;
                doc.EffectiveDate = effectiveDate;
                doc.CalcBase = calcBase;
                doc.Value = value.HasValue ? value.Value : 0;
                doc.CostCenter = costCenter;
                doc.SubAcc = subAcc;
                doc.DocReference = docReference;
                doc.Comment = comment;
            }
            dbu.Entry<NIOCPay_PayDetail>(doc).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            dbu.NIOCPay_PayDetail.Attach(doc);                                
            dbu.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

document entity updated and savechanges method runs without any errors but not in database also I was runing SQL Profiler at the same time and I found out nothing happend there was no sql or any executive sql command. what should I do regarding this?

Comment: You can shorten the selection clause: the 'Where' is redundant. You can place the lambda in the SingleOrDefault method.

Comment: what is different between them ? it is not related to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my own answer :

```
db.NIOCPay_PayDetail.Attach(doc);
db.ChangeTracker.Entries<NIOCPay_PayDetail>().FirstOrDefault().State =
                               System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

now it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to just switch the order of the following lines: `dbu.Entry<NIOCPay_PayDetail>(doc).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
dbu.NIOCPay_PayDetail.Attach(doc);`

Comment: Yes, I did, it doesn't work. Tracker doesn't change by using that.

Answer (score 0):

> document updated and savechanges method runs without any errors

does it means that your changes are saved to database?

**If yes** then it means that your profiler settings are not correct and it could be because of multiple reasons like you are running on wrong database, you have set some parameters which are incorrect and so on. 
**If No** then your statement is wrong. Please diagnose where is the problem